# Squid or DansGuardian: Which should pass content to an antivirus product for scanning?

Tags: server, clamav, squid

I have an Ubuntu Server12.04 installation acting as a proxy server using Squid 3.1.19.

Squid has been configured to pass content to SquidClamAV 6.10 to check for viruses (using icap):

```
icap_service service_req reqmod_precache bypass=1 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squidclamav
adaptation_access service_req allow all
icap_service service_resp respmod_precache bypass=1 icap://127.0.0.1:1344/squidclamav
adaptation_access service_resp allow all
```

The current setup works perfectly well, but now I’d like to install DansGuardian to provide content filtering.

Like Squid, the DansGuardian config file (/etc/dansguardian/dansguardian.conf) can also be integrated with anti-virus products using the 'contentscanner' directive.

Should I ignore the 'contentscanner' directive in DansGuardian and leave Squid in charge of passing content to SquidClamAV. Or should I have DansGuardian pass content to an anti-virus product? Or should they both be passing content to anti-virus products?

What’s considered best practice? Are there any advantages/disadvantages either way?